# Python: 'other_activity' is not defined

Tags: python

I want to print the `other_activity` if its not empty after taking input from user but this error, I know its pretty basic but not able to find the solution

```
print("What kind of activity is this?")
print '\n'.join(acti)

userInput = raw_input("\n""Client->")
r = re.compile(userInput)
if not filter(r.match, acti):
        print("not valid activity")

else:
    if (userInput == "Other"):
        event_activity = raw_input("-> Please specify your activity\n""Client->")
        other_activity = ("Other:" + event_activity)
    else:
        event_activity = userInput

if not other_activity:
    print("Activity type: ", other_activity)
else:
    print("Activity type: ", event_activity)
```

Comment: Not all branches of your code define `other_activity`, therefore it's possible that on some execution branches Python will throw a `NameError` because it does not know what `other_activity` is supposed to be.

Comment: what is the solution then, how I should define? should I make it global?

Comment: if other_activity:
    print("Activity type: ", other_activity)

Comment: @Djee same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `other_activity = None` at the top of your code (*There are cases in your code when `other_activity` is never assigned, and thus, never created. By adding this default assignment, you are making sure the variable will exist when checking its value*)

At the end, you can use a ternary condition to print one variable or the other:

```
print('Activity type:', other_activity if other_activity else event_activity)
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't remember those dynamic languages, supposed to be easy going, are so verbose. I thought *if xxx:* would nicely fail if *xxx* was not defined...